# Finding total null values in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    (1, 1, None), 
    (1, 2, float(5)), 
    (1, 3, np.nan), 
    (1, 4, None), 
    (1, 5, float(10)), 
    (1, 6, float("nan")), 
    (1, 6, float("nan")),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("session", "timestamp1", "id2"))
```

I am trying to find the total number of null or None values using to get output

```
df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
+-------+----------+---+
|session|timestamp1|id2|
+-------+----------+---+
|      0|         0|  5|
+-------+----------+---+
```

But it fails when there is a date and timestamp type column. The solution I found for that is

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def count_missings(spark_df,sort=True):
    """
    Counts number of nulls and nans in each column
    """
    df = spark_df.select([F.count(F.when(F.isnan(c) | F.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for (c,c_type) in spark_df.dtypes if c_type not in ('timestamp', 'string', 'date')]).toPandas()

    if len(df) == 0:
        print("There are no any missing values!")
        return None

    if sort:
        return df.rename(index={0: 'count'}).T.sort_values("count",ascending=False)

    return df
```

But it is very time computationally expensive. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: converting to pandas is expensive, is it really necessary to use pandas?

Comment: @AdibP No it's not necessary to use pandas, that's why I am trying to figure out a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create tempview of the dataframe and than query it with sql.
For your example lets change type of the id2 column to timestamp:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('timestmp_type', to_timestamp(col('id2')))
new_df.show()

+-------+----------+----+-------------------+
|session|timestamp1| id2|      timestmp_type|
+-------+----------+----+-------------------+
|      1|         1|null|               null|
|      1|         2| 5.0|1970-01-01 00:00:05|
|      1|         3| NaN|               null|
|      1|         4|null|               null|
|      1|         5|10.0|1970-01-01 00:00:10|
|      1|         6| NaN|               null|
|      1|         6| NaN|               null|
+-------+----------+----+-------------------+
```

Than create tempview:

```
new_df.createOrReplaceTempView("timestamp_null_count_view")
```

After that you can write query with spark sql to find number of null in the timestamp or whatever column.

```
spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM timestamp_null_count_view where timestmp_type IS NULL").show()
```